# Сохранение данных нескольких таблиц и нескольких textarea

Tags: javascript

нужно сохранить в localStorage данные по нажатию кнопки. Файл хранится на сетевой папке с общим доступом, нужно чтобы люди зайдя в данный файл ввели данные в textarea, выбрали чекбоксами персонал и технику далее нажали Сохранить и при следующем открытии файла отобразились сохраненные данные.

````
<h1>Форма</h1>   

 <textarea  id="text" cols="70" rows="4" placeholder="Наименование объекта."></textarea> 
   <br>
    <textarea  id="text2" cols="90" rows="4" placeholder="Наименование работ, заказ."></textarea>
    
  
    <script>
  document.write('<h1>Персонал</h1>')
FIO = [
  "",
  "Е.В. Иванов, начальник отдела",
  "А.А. Соколов, инженер 1 категории",
  "Ю.В. Сидоров, инженер 1 категории",
  "Ю.Е. Трудный, инженер 1 категории",
  "А.В. Башман, инженер 1 категории",
  "В.В. Вилов, инженер 1 категории",
  "Е.А. Петров, инженер 1 категории"
];

document.write('<table border = "1">')
for (var i = 1; i < FIO.length; i++) { // если var i=0; то появится "", то есть при i=1 список формируется со 2 строки
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(i);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(FIO[i]);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='checkbox'>");
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");

   
   document.write('<h1>Техника</h1>')     
  
Technika = [
  "",
"Автомобиль Вахта НЕФАЗ-4208-03",
"Автомобиль Вахта НЕФАЗ-4208-11-1",
"Автомобиль Вахта УРАЛ 32551-5113-71",
"Автомобиль ПАЗ 320412",
"Автомобиль НЕФАЗ -5299-01",
"Автомобиль НеФАЗ -5299-11-31",
"Автомобиль УРАЛ-4320",
"Автомобиль УРАЛ-5557",
"Автомобиль грузовой КМУ ГИРД",
];

document.write('<table border = "1">')
for (var j = 1; j < Technika.length; j++) { 
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(j);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(Technika[j]);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='checkbox'>");
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");        
  
   
 document.write("<br><button>Удалить не выделенные строки!</button>")

function removeRows() {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
    
    Array.from(inputs)
        .filter(input => !input.checked)
        .forEach(input => {
            const row = input.closest('tr')
            
            row.remove()
        })

    Array.from(inputs)
        .filter(input => input.checked)
        .forEach((input, idx) => {
            const row = input.closest('tr')
            const first = row.children[0]

            first.textContent = idx + 1
        })
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.onclick = removeRows
        
    </script>   
    
    
    
 <br><br><br>
    <button id="save">Сохранить</button> ```
````

Comment: Может пора использовать некий сервер, пусть и запущенный только в локальной сети на некоем компе... Это всяко лучше чем "файл в локалке и общим доступом".